# Are there any linkage or transformation between some period transcendental numbers and algebraic irrational numbers?

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, reference-request, riemann-surfaces, arithmetic-geometry

Are there any linkage or transformation by combination of integral and algebraic function like in the definition of period number between  some  period transcendental numbers and algebraic irrational numbers,especially these irrational algebraic number exceeding degree 2? The relation or linkage between transcendental constants like $ \pi,e,\dots$ and algebraic irrational numbers,especially these irrational algebraic number exceeding degree 2 is much interesting to me.

Comment: This seems much too broad/vague as it currently stands.  There are any number of ways of constructing transcendentals out of particular algebraics - for instance, you can use the expression for $\sin(\frac\pi5)$ to reconstruct a rational multiple of $\pi$ as the integral of $\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ between two quartic values, etc.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki,Yes,what I want to know is about the relation between some specific irrational algebraic numbers exceeding degree 2 and transcendental one,for we can get some information about coefficients of continued fraction of algebraic number from relevant transcendental number

Comment: _Which_ specific irrational algebraics?  Which specific transcendental numbers?  Why would you expect to be able to get CF coefficients out of a period integral relation?

Comment: Why not provide that context (re: your comment) directly in your post.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki,it is a try,I somehow feel some information about CF coefficients of algebraic number can be gotten from relevant transcendental period number.Maybe people think I do things unreasonably,but such a way usually make me a way out.